# numbers getting append at end while printing

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal

I am working with a program which mimics digital clock. While running it on terminal, my results are like `21:2:139` the 9 append at the end. However, on java console it print as perfect `20:59:0`.

my code:

```
public static void myClock(int h, int m) throws Exception{
        //int minutes = m;
        int s = 00;
        while (true) {
            if(s != 60) {
                System.out.print("\t\t"+h+":"+m+":"+s+"\r");
                Thread.sleep(50);
                s += 01;
            }else {
                m += 1;
                s=00;
                if(m==60) {
                    m = 00;
                    h += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know why it's happening because I am new to linux and java.

Comment: Note that numeric literals prefixed with `0` are octal values.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't use `\r`. Different consoles interpret that differently. That's why you have such artifacts. The "9" could come from a previous output, that hasn't be overwritten, since the new output was shorter.

Comment: Remark: `public static void myClock(int h, int m) throws Exception{` - you should throw a specific `Exception` (in your case `InterruptedException`) or handle the exception within the method.